# Is it ok to include unbalanced covariates in regression after full matching?

Tags: causality, matching, covariate-balance

A couple of my covariates remained imbalanced after full matching. Is it acceptable to include those imbalanced covariates in the post-matching regression analysis (in addition to the matching weights)? or could this introduce bias?

The alternative would be to conduct genetic matching (where all covariates were balanced but the ESS < 30).

Answer (score 0):

I guarantee there is a matching method that can achieve better balance than you have without decreasing the ESS so much, but yes, it is acceptable (and advised!) to include covariates after any kind of matching. The `MatchIt` vignette on estimating effect explains how to do this. Regression after matching is equivalent to eliminating imbalance on the covariate means, but it doesn't reduce other forms of imbalance and can sometimes make it worse.

The `lmw` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lmw) helps to assess the affect of regression on the imbalance of the covariates after matching. See [Chattopadhyay et al. (2022)](http://arxiv.org/abs/2303.08790) for instructions on how to use the package. Section 5.3 is specifically for using regression after matching.

The idea is that doing regression is equivalent to estimating propensity score weights, where the weights have a specific form. So you can assess balance after estimating those regression weights, which gives a picture of the imbalance in the sample that would remain after running the regression. If imbalance remains or gets worse after regression, then you should seek to find a better matching algorithm or make other changes, which might involve sacrificing the estimand to be able to attain balance (e.g., by using a caliper).

If you are interested in trying a new matching method that might outperform the ones available in `MatchIt`, try the energy distance matching frontier in the `MatchingFrontier` package. Instructions for use are on its [website](https://iqss.github.io/MatchingFrontier/).